# CakePHP 3 : Can't display all data when I use first() then foreach()

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I'm a beginner with CakePHP 3. My question is when we use `first()` in a view on a query that contains a lot of records, is it possible to get the other records using `foreach()`? Example :

```
<?=$query->first()->id ?>
// some code here 
<?= foreach($query as $value) : ?>
    <?=$value->name ?>
    <?=$value->created ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

When I do this I don't get all the records, just the first one, even if I use `foreach()`. But when I delete the line `<?=$query->first()->id ?>` I get all the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query has not been executed, the line

```
$query->first()->id
```

executes the query and applies a `LIMIT 1` clause.

The following should fetch all the records and return the first.

```
$query->all()->first()
```

From the Cookboox 3.x:

- [Getting the First Result](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-the-first-result)
- [Getting the First & Last Record From a ResultSet](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-the-first-last-record-from-a-resultset)